# Funcionamento do Non-standard evaluation (NSE) em R

Tags: r

Na maioria das linguagens de programação, você só pode acessar os valores dos argumentos de uma função. Mas, em `R`, você também pode acessar o código usado para computá-los.

Este [trecho](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-expressions) do capítulo *non-standard evaluation* também fala sobre a função `substitute`, a qual transforma o argumento da função em uma *promise*.
Eu não entendi muito sobre `substitute` e *promises*, eu não sei se por falta de exemplos ou exemplos complexos demais (isso é muito subjetivo) dado pelo autor.

Por exemplo, neste trecho traduzido:

> "Normalmente, você não está ciente das promessas porque, na primeira vez que acessa uma promessa, seu código é avaliado em seu ambiente, gerando um valor."

O exemplo dado pelo autor foi esse:

```
f <- function(x) {
  substitute(x)
}

f(1:10)
#> 1:10

x <- 10
f(x)
#> x
```

Ainda há o uso das funções `eval` e `quote`, mas não fez muito sentido pois não consegui entender o funcionamento e utilidade de `substitute`.

Assim, eu tenho duas perguntas (que são relacionadas):

- Qual é a utilidade de usar o *non-standard evaluation* em `R`?
- Onde usar [`substitute`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substitute), `eval` e `quote`? (se alguém puder oferecer um exemplo diferente do livro, mais didático, ajudaria a entender...)

Como eu disse, o capítulo explica isso, mas eu não consegui entender bem esses conceitos. Na verdade, eu não sei se isso importa no cotidiano de um analista de dados ou é mais relevante pra quem cria pacotes em `R` ou outros trabalhos paralelos a este último.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Non-standard evaluation" permite chamar e avaliar expressões desde outros ambientes diferentes ao ambiente global ou um ambiente específico em que o usuário está trabalhando. Isso porque no R, usuários podem manipular as expressões da linguagem antes que elas sejam executadas.

Geralmente quando se trabalha em R, você cria objetos e muitos desses
objetos são salvos no ambiente de trabalho (".GlobalEnv").
Por exemplo esses objetos são criados:

```
x <- c(1:5)

y <- letters[1:5]

set.seed(45)

z <- rnorm(5)

dxy <- data.frame(x, y = LETTERS[6:10], z)
```

Eles devem aparecer na sessão:

```
objects()
#> [1] "dxy" "x"   "y"   "z"
```

E podem ser removidos

```
rm(z) # removendo "z"
```

Esses objetos são "avaliados" por padrão ("standard-evaluation") no ambiente de trabalho quando se executa uma operação ou se mostra o conteúdo deles.

```
dxy
#   x y          z
# 1 1 F  0.3407997
# 2 2 G -0.7033403
# 3 3 H -0.3795377
# 4 4 I -0.7460474
# 5 5 J -0.8981073
```

No capítulo do [livro](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-expressions) [`quote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) e [`eval`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/eval) são usados para exemplificar a diferença entre expressões ou nomes que são [objetos da linguagem](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Language-objects) e o resultado da avaliação de uma expressão ou um "statement". Isso facilita entender o que é uma "promessa" no contexto de uma função e a relação com "non-standard evaluation".

Por exemplo, o seguinte objeto da linguagem é uma expressão que representa uma ação que pode ser executada no R:

```
xz <- quote(x + z^2)

xz
# x + z^2
```

```
class(xz)
# [1] "call"
```

```
typeof(xz)
# [1] "language"
```

O objeto é um "call" que tem o "código para computar". Para executar o conteúdo desse nome, pode ser usada a função `eval`. Esse novo objeto já é um vector numérico que resulta de executar a operação contida no nome:

```
exz <- eval(xz)
```

```
class(exz)
# [1] "numeric"
```

```
typeof(exz)
# [1] "double"
```

A função [`substitute`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substitute) permite, entre outras coisas, elaborar funções que fogem da avaliação padrão do R no ambiente de trabalho e substituir o chamado para objetos que estão em outros ambientes, em tabelas ou dataframes. Muitas funções de pacotes como ggplot2, ou dplyr usam esse método para poder manipular objetos que estão dentro de tabelas ao invés de objetos do ambiente global. Isso permite escrever um código menos verboso.

Nesse exemplo do livro de Wickham é apresentada a lógica usando uma função chamada [`subset2`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset).

```
subset2 <- function(x, condition) {
    condition_call <- substitute(condition) # cria o "parse tree", sustitui variáveis do ambiente
    r <- eval(condition_call, x) # a expressão anterior é avaliada no ambiente "x" (uma tabela)
    x[r, ]
}
```

A função permite extrair valores de uma tabela. `substitute` é usada para capturar a chamada que é realizada pelo usuário e avalia a expressão dentro da tabela, ao invés de chamar um objeto que está no ambiente global:

```
subset2(dxy, z > 0)
#   x y         z
# 1 1 F 0.3407997
```

A função aplica "non-standard evaluation" sobre o vector z que está na tabela: antes que a expressão seja executada no ambiente global, a chamada é passada para a tabela e é executada a seleção de linhas dentro da tabela, ao invés de procurar por um objeto no ambiente.

Outras funções que operam de maneira similar como o `subset` "original" ou `with` usam o mesmo princípio.

```
subset(dxy, z > 0)
#   x y         z
# 1 1 F 0.3407997
```

```
with(dxy, z >0)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`substitute` deve ser usada quando se quer construir funções com "non-standard evaluation". Usar `quote` conduz a erros. Se a função "subset" é construída usando `quote`, a avaliação do código será padrão (standard evaluation):

```
subset3 <- function(x, condition) {
    condition_call <- quote(condition)
    r <- eval(condition_call, x)
    x[r, ]
}
```

A função não consegue achar dito objeto que está na tabela porque está procurando "z" no ambiente global

```
subset3(dxy, z > 0)
# Error in eval(condition_call, x) : object 'z' not found
```

A documentação do pacote [lazyeval](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) aprofunda o conceito de "non-standard evaluation" no R.